# Can a Java Applet minimize its browser window?

Tags: java, applet

My applet pops up in a browser window and then creates a separate JFrame. I'd like to minimize the original hosting browser window. Can I do it from the applet?

Comment: Sounds like the 'tail wagging the dog' or the 'guest burning down the guest house'.  Don't do it.  It is not the responsibility of an applet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't minimize a browser window from the Applet or with Javascript. You can try playing around with the Javascript window `blur` and `focus` to see if you can make them work for you. Communicating with JS should be possible as follows

```
import netscape.javascript.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
class MyApplet extends Applet {
  public void init() {
    JSObject win = JSObject.getWindow(this);
    JSObject doc = (JSObject) win.getMember("document");
    JSObject loc = (JSObject) doc.getMember("location");

    String s = (String) loc.getMember("href");  // document.location.href
    win.call("f", null);                 // Call f() in HTML page
  }
}
```

Code untested and taken from [Oracle docs](http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.3/docs/jsobject.html)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do it.  Your applet does not gain control over the calling window and therefore can't minimize (or otherwise manipulate) that window.