# how to minimize a web browser from on an button click from a jsp page?

Tags: jsp, struts-1

how to minimize a web browser from on an button click from a jsp page?

The jsp code snippet is as below.

```
<html:form action="CallAction.do?option=case1" method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="DoAction"/>
</html:form>
```

The corresponing java sturts code snippet is as follows:

```
public class CallAction extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {

    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        String forward = "";
        String option = "";
        CallForm callForm = (CallForm) form;
        option = callForm.getOption();

        if (option.equals("case1")) {
            new doAction().init();
            forward = "welcome";
        }

        return mapping.findForward(forward);
    }    
}
```

I want to minimize the web browser window once the `DoAction` button is submitted

Comment: You can't minimize the browser window. In fact, you can't control the browser from webpage

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/11510765/485608

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using purely client side code, e.g. javascript.

Take a look on the following post for details: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471151/MinimizeMaximize-a-Browser-Window.htm

Or google "minimize browser window using javascript".

Since this question is not about java but about javascript I am fixing the tagging of this question.